# Google Maps doesn't work when inside a div

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API and the div that is going to contain the map works only when not inside another div. I've created a little sample code with two maps, the first works the second doesn't. If I remove the doctype of this piece of code, both work. Any ideas why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta content='application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='content-type' />
    <style type='text/css'>
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 50% }
        #map_canvas2 { height: 50% }
    </style>
    <title>Map</title>
    <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function initialize() {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20, 20);
          var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), myOptions);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload='initialize()'>
    <div id='map_canvas'></div>
    <div>
      <div id='map_canvas2'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks like in Firefox and Chrome:

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: @matpol: there, I uploaded how I see it in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Apparently, the transitional doctype also works, so I'm going with that.

Answer (score 5):

It does work, If you inspect the page in firebug, you'll see that the map is being created. But because you have no CSS positioning applied to the outer div, the map div created by Google maps is positioned under the first map_canvas

You need to position and set the dimensions for the outer div, try by giving the outer div a pixel height and pixel width...

**EDIT**

instead of :

```
<div id='map_canvas'></div>
<div>
  <div id='map_canvas2'></div>
</div>
```

try :

```
<!--<div id='map_canvas'></div>-->
<div style="width:900px;height:900px;">
  <div id='map_canvas2'></div>
</div>
```

You will see the map is working...

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Comment out the first map and you'll see zero maps. If you were correct you should still see one map.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are sitting on top of each other or something - change the height on the css to pixel heights and both maps will work

Comment: No, they are not sitting on top of each other. My original bug is that the map is not being shown. I created this example with two maps just to show when it's shown and when it isn't. If you comment out the first map you see zero maps.

Comment: if comment out everything to do(ie the javascript call) with map 1 and give a height in pixels to map 2 it works. If you set both heights to pixels both maps work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload='initialize()'>
   <div>
      <div id='map_canvas'></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It shows nothing (that's my original problem, this is just an example that shows that the JavaScript is working).