# google map is not working inside website

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, google-maps-markers

```js
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = '';
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'map.png'
          }
        };

        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
            type: 'info'
          }
        ];

        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        });
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDeuMlx32V1fYT3wRAa1wEjjtQuAI6wATM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:100%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Google map with custom marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ1XY.jpg)

hello i am using Google map inside my website.i want to add my logo.png instead of Google marker.i have generated key from Google page & added it inside the script tag. i have followed all the steps given on the Google page i have written the following code for it.but when i use the following code it shows nothing.i want to design same layout as shown in image.

Comment: What does the output of your console say? The Maps API can only be used on pages served via HTTPS.

Comment: Where is your js located? It works for me if I put it in a <script> tag in html.

Comment: in the same page

Comment: i have also put the code in the script tag

Comment: <div class=row> is a height of 0 pixel

Answer (score 0):

you should set a size to your `div#map` like so:

```
#map1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Adjust according your needs of course.

Comment: i have added the #map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
} but its not working

Comment: Try inline like so: `<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:100%"></div>`

Comment: @LakhanKhandelwal Do you only tryied on **jsfiddle**? Do you tried also on a real browser?

Comment: @LakhanKhandelwal On jsfiddle, it doesn't work when I tried. But on jsbin it does. Now it doesn't anymore but in the meantime does your API key still valid? Also, do not forget to use `#map1` since in the code you provided you set the id to `map1` not `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the outer divs. just remove and try your code works.
refer this question : [Google Maps doesn't work when inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195187/google-maps-doesnt-work-when-inside-a-div)

```js
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = '';
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'map.png'
          }
        };

        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
            type: 'info'
          }
        ];

        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        });
      }
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDeuMlx32V1fYT3wRAa1wEjjtQuAI6wATM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    
<div class="row"  style="width: 100%; height:100%">
 <div id="map"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: its working in another page but when i add this code inside my project within <div class="row"> its not working

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem goes to integrating google map with bootstrap.In details, you should set the css height style of map tag's parent div(.container-fluid) to 100%;

In order to make the following demo run normally,you should provide your google map api key and your picture file for the marker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
        
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        
        html,
        body,
        .container-fluid {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var map;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {
                    lat: 26.880,
                    lng: 112.644
                },
                zoom: 8
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.880, 112.644),
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                icon: '/images/github-youtube.jpg'// your image file path
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- your google map api key : xxxx-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

PS: this is the first time I used google maps,so maybe some code is weird.I have tried as the following procedure.

1.see google maps getting started page.

2.add customized marker.

3.integrate with bootstrap.

Hope it can help you.